# AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory cannot be converted to JiraRestClientFactory

Tags: java, rest, maven, jira, pom.xml

I'm trying to do some very basic Jira interaction using the REST API, but failing at every hurdle. I haven't even tried sending any requests or anything yet, I'm simply trying to initialize the client. I got most of the following code online from others who were using it, but for some reason, I can't get it to work.

I keep getting this compilation error:

```
com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory cannot be converted to com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.JiraRestClientFactory
```

My .java file looks like this:

```
package com.atlassian.tutorial.macro;

import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.ConversionContext;
import com.atlassian.confluence.macro.Macro;
import com.atlassian.confluence.macro.MacroExecutionException;

import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.JiraRestClient;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.JiraRestClientFactory;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.domain.User;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory;
import com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promise;

import java.net.URI;

import java.util.Map;

public class helloworld implements Macro {

    private static final String JIRA_URL = "http://localhost:2990/jira";
    private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME = "admin";
    private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "admin";

    public String execute(Map<String, String> map, String s, ConversionContext conversionContext) throws MacroExecutionException {

        JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
        URI uri = new URI(JIRA_URL);
        JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD);
   }

        public BodyType getBodyType() { return BodyType.NONE; }
        public OutputType getOutputType() { return OutputType.BLOCK; }
}
```

And my pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.atlassian.tutorial</groupId>
<artifactId>myConfluenceMacro</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<organization>
    <name>Test</name>
    <url>http://www.example.com/</url>
</organization>

<name>myConfluenceMacro</name>
<description>This is the com.atlassian.tutorial:myConfluenceMacro plugin for Atlassian Confluence.</description>
<packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

<dependencies>
     <!-->JIRA LINK STUFF<-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2-2bd0a62e</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-parent</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-m25</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- JRJC depends on a newer version of atlassian-util-concurrent than the one provided by JIRA -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.util.concurrent</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-util-concurrent</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <!-- JRJC uses 4.0 of the apache httpclient. JIRA bundled version 3.x -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-m2</version>
        <!--
         JIRA will already provide a number of dependencies that JRJC needs. We need to exclude them from the
         JRJC dependency as we don't want to package them up inside the plugin.
        -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.sal</groupId>
                <artifactId>sal-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.event</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-event</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-->/////////////////////////<-->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
        <artifactId>confluence</artifactId>
        <version>${confluence.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation</artifactId>
        <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
        <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>confluence-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${amps.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <productVersion>${confluence.version}</productVersion>
                <productDataVersion>${confluence.data.version}</productDataVersion>
                <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>

                <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                <instructions>
                    <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>

                    <!-- Add package to export here -->
                    <Export-Package>
                        com.atlassian.tutorial.api,
                    </Export-Package>

                    <!-- Add package import here -->
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",
                        org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional",
                        *
                    </Import-Package>

                    <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                    <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>atlassian-spring-scanner</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <scannedDependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-external-jar</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </scannedDependencies>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <confluence.version>6.14.0</confluence.version>
    <confluence.data.version>6.14.0</confluence.data.version>
    <amps.version>8.0.2</amps.version>
    <plugin.testrunner.version>2.0.1</plugin.testrunner.version>
    <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.13</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
    <!-- This property ensures consistency between the key in atlassian-plugin.xml and the OSGi bundle's key. -->
    <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your maven POM, you are using two different versions of the jira implementation. 
They most likely have the same naming scheme, and is probably why you are getting the "AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory cannot be converted to JiraRestClientFactory" error, because even though the naming is the same, the classes are coming from two different dependency jars (5.1.2) & (4.0.0)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2-2bd0a62e</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-parent</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Joe, I'm now getting lots of errors saying 'SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process'